# Upon publishing my project, "Do not merge" option doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, merge, plesk

Lately I start using PLESK system ,creating my site, so I published my project to the server, but see I got only aspx files ( meaning .cs and .designer files disappear ).
As I read on the web,I've realized that those files got merged into a dll file in the "bin" folder.
Now , upon publishing the project, I tried to use the "Do not merge" option, but the .cs and the .designer files, still not showing up. (I am using visual studio 2015).

So I have got two questions :

.1. How can I fix it? Why can't I still see the files?

.2.Can I see the merged dll file? Because I'm not sure which file is it on the "bin" folder.

.

Thanks for all those who can help :)

Comment: Why do you care if the cs files are published?

Comment: So I can edit the .cs files via the plesk system , instead of edit it in my local visual studio and publish the whole project every time. Is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: No, the code is compiled into the DLL, to re-compile them requires a build system.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a build system in plesk ?

Comment: Why would you want that? It's dangerous to allow that kind of thing - I would strongly recommend not doing that.

Comment: So the way I should doing it is change the code in my local visual studio, then build and publish it every time I want to make changes?

This is my first site, so I'm just wondering if this is the way most programmers doing it.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better way to do it. Means you can test your code works before you publish it live. Imagine you make a typo, it could take your site down very easily. A more advanced system would use a CI/CD system to do the build and release process.

Comment: I guess that's really a better way, but my project is not done yet, and the reason I've loaded it to the server was because I needed a number of users getting into my site. (For example,In order to get into one of my pages, it is needed to have 5 users in the same page on the same time). So that's the reason I can't really check my code in my local computer. And checking it every time on the web and then change the code in visual studio ,rebuild and republish it, could take a lot of time. 

That's the reason I asked for a way changing the .cs code in the plesk system.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments to your question.  However, you could consider inline code.  This would allow you to publish the page with the code in it, without having to compile.  There's numerous examples by searching for

> aspx inline c#

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Page Language="c#"%>

<script runat="server">
  public string ServerSideFunction(string input)
  {
    return "Hello " + input;
  }
</script>

<% string pageVariable = "world"; %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>ASP.NET inline</title>
</head>
<body>
<% =ServerSideFunction(pageVariable) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, basicly by this method, I do not even need a .cs file ?
Can I write my whole code like this ? I mean, including a database connection, some calculations, and more..

Comment: Correct.  No .cs file.  You lose the benefits of precompiling (and probably some others), but you get the benefit of quick/easy deployment.